I getting this error in my terminal while performing "flutter run". What to do?
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':package_info_plus:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.


error: invalid source release: 17


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.


Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 23s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                             86.6s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
I have tried and changed the jdk version but nothing happens

Try using the latest version of plugin.

Does this answer your question? Execution Failed for task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac in Android Studio


clean your project using "flutter clean".

downgrade package_info_plus version which you used in lsat time when your project runnig fine.

if you didn't use package_info_plus anytime in your project the put any in pubspec.yaml file like this :
package_info_plus : any

then flutter pub get

run project




Try to create the Flutter project in Android Studio and open it from there, I think the folder has been excluded windows from Windows Defender.

if didn't work try to copy the jbr files to jre folder. jbr files
